# What does it mean for a perturbation expansion to break down?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

For an anharmonic oscillator with Hamiltonian $H = {\hat p_x^2\over 2m}+{1\over 2}m\omega^2\hat x^2+b\hat x^4$ I found the first order shift in energy is:

$$E_n^{(1)}={3 \hbar^2 b\over 4m^2\omega^2}\big(1+2n+n^2\big)$$

Now I need to argue that no matter how small b is, the perturbation expansion will break down for sufficiently large $n$. I know that the energy will keep increasing as $n$ increases because $b$ is a constant, but I don't know what it means for a "perturbation expansion to break down." What does this mean?

Comment: Do you have a source making this claim for the given Hamiltonian? Please let me know. I am interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic assumption behind perturbation theory is that $E_n^{(1)}$ should be “much smaller” than the unperturbed energy $E_n^{(0)}$.  This assumption clearly is no longer value for sufficiently large $n$ irrespective of $b$ since the correction grows like $n^2$ while the unperturbed energy grows like $n$.  There is no “hard and fast” rule as to when perturbation theory break down because “much smaller” is rather qualitative, but you *might* look at the point where corrections are - say - $20\%$ or more of the unperturbed energy as a point where the correction is no longer small.

You might also look at the first correction to eigenstate: if the unperturbed state is not “significantly more” probable than the other states in the perturbed eigenstate then perturbation theory can be said to be invalid.

Comment: That’s a really nice explanation, thank you. Do you know what this would mean physically? It seems like if the perturbation energy is much larger than the unperturbed energy it would cause some strange motion in an oscillator.

Comment: @matryoshka the initial guess of the unperturbed Hamiltonian is no longer valid.  In your case, you cannot think of the state as being “something like a h.o. state”.  Classically frequency would depend on the energy.

Answer (score 2):

In a perturbative series, you want successive corrections to be smaller than the previous ones, so that you get a convergent result. This breaks down if higher-order shifts get larger, which you can readily see will happen as $n$ grows large.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you want to compute corrections to some observable $f_0$:
$$f(x) = \sum_{k \leq N} f_k \, x^{k} + O(x^{N+1}).$$
This is a good estimate only if the tail
$$\lVert \, f(x) - \sum_{k \leq N} f_k \, x^{k} \rVert = \lVert \, f_{N+1} x^{N+1} + \ldots \rVert$$
is small. If the first error term $f_{N+1} x^{N+1}$ is of the same order as the LHS, the tail is probably large and you're not doing something sensible. In your case $N=0$, but you can still get a feeling if perturbation theory will work by requiring that $E_n^{(1)} \ll E_n^{(0)}$.